# Imagemagick how to delete all colors expect black

Tags: imagemagick

I have question. Is it possible to delete all colors from image, but save the black color? I have a picture with several unknown colors. (Therefore I can't just replace e.g red color with white color). I have an image like this:

[image]

And I am trying to delete this "Text2" and "Text3". Is that possible? Which option in Imagemagick should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark's answer is probably the best if you easily can separate the black region from the rest of the image, since it preserves the antialiased text better. However, if not then you can do something similar to Bonzo's command. Here is another variation of that.

```
convert EWwSX.jpg -fuzz 40% -fill white +opaque black result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Can You help me to convert this to c#? Now I'm having something like that:
image.ColorFuzz = (Percentage)40;
image.Settings.FillColor = MagickColors.White;
image.Opaque(MagickColors.Black, MagickColors.Black);
image.Write(@"C:\OR\OCRX\x.jpg");

Comment: Sorry, I do not code C#. You could ask on the ImageMagick Discourse server at https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your question - you can't really delete a colour in an image. What would be left? I understand you can't replace the red with white because you have reds elsewhere in your image.

I guess the easiest thing to do is draw a white rectangle over the unwanted text:

```
convert text.jpg -fill white -draw "rectangle 20,72 100,150" result.jpg
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not a great result but with some tweeking or work you could improve it:

```
convert EWwSX.jpg -threshold 20% black.png
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Aha! Maybe that's what was meant :-)